# Updating old authnetcc class from authorize net for new API release

Tags: php, authorize.net

**Background**

I am working on a 10 year old website that uses a very old `AIM class` from authorize.net. The end point that this website is using to hit authorize.net api is deprecated on the 28th of this month. I was told that I must use the new URL endpoint.

[A full list of URLs scheduled for disablement can be found here.](https://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A1623&pmv=print&impressions=false&actp=LIST)

The site is currently using

```
https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll
```

This is the suggested production URL

```
https://test.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api
```

This is the suggested sandbox URL

```
https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api
```

I am trying to figure out the easiest way to update the SDK with minimal amounts of changes to the existing code base. We are in the process of creating a new site and do not want to spend more time than necessary to keep this one working.

When I change the URL, the request fails with an error. The current site is sending key name value pairs in a URL string.

When looking for information about how to update this I found this paragraph on their website.

> Advanced Integration Method (AIM)
>
> STATUS: Supported but no longer updated
>
> ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION: Use the methods described in Payment
>   Transactions in the the API Reference using XML or JSON.
>
> DESCRIPTION: All of the transaction methods previously available
>   through AIM are possible using the methods described in Payment
>   Transactions in the the API Reference using XML or JSON. If you are
>   using transaction methods documented as part of what we previously
>   called our "AIM XML" API, these transaction methods have been
>   incorporated into our current broader Authorize.Net API. These
>   transaction requests can continue to be used as is.
>
> If you are using our legacy AIM Name Value Pair (NVP) method, you're
>   posting your transaction requests to a URL ending in "transact.dll",
>   and the form field names begin with "x_". These types of transaction
>   requests can be brought current by recreating them using the methods
>   described in Payment Transactions in the the API Reference using XML
>   or JSON.
>
> If you are using our legacy AIM Name Value Pair (NVP) method and need
>   to troubleshoot existing code, you may find it helpful to refer to the
>   existing AIM NVP documentation: AIM NVP Guide (PDF), PayPal AIM NVP
>   Guide (PDF)

I am a confused by this line,

> These types of transaction requests can be brought current by
>   recreating them using the methods described in Payment Transactions in
>   the the API Reference using XML or JSON.

I know they are referring to their [new API which can be seen here.](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#payment-transactions) But I am confused about the "recreating them using the methods" part.

**Question**

In what way can we update this old class to work with the new authroize.net api? Is the suggested way to completely rewrite the whole existing class to be functions from their new api using their new SDK? The statement mentioned above is unclear to me.

Does anyone know if this has been done open source by anyone I could quickly update the class in our project with?

**Old authnetcc class**

```
class authnetcc {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the endpoint:

```
https://secure2.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll
```

This is documented in the [AIM Developer Guide (PDF)](https://www.authorize.net/content/dam/authorize/documents/AIM_guide.pdf) on Page 34 (September 2017).

AuthorizeNet encourages developers to move away from legacy methods, but they are still supported although only updates for security issues will be made. You might have to learn the SDK and write new code, but it's hard to say without a complete use case and existing code.

Comment: The link you mentioned is also being disabled on February 28th. I am trying to find the best way to migrate. I would assume other people are facing the same problem as me. If so, I would think other people have had to update the authnetcc class. If this one class was updated with the same function names then the whole application would continue to work. Minus the changes in the response. You can see the list of URLs to be disabled at the bottom of the page at this link, https://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A1623&pmv=print&impressions=false&actp=LIST

Comment: They're disabling TLS v1.0 and 1.1, not the URL. You need to use TLS v1.2. You can force TLS v1.2 in your code. But without a code sample, I can't advise further.